# Declaring a function with types of arguments taken from a foreign parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Suppose I have some kind of type list

```
template<typename... Types> struct TypeList {};
```

Now in some other class I can generate such a `TypeList` in a variety of ways.

```
template<class T> struct MyClass {
    using MyList = TypeList<T, typename Something<T>::type, SomethingElse>;
    // ...
};
```

How can I declare a method with types of arguments extracted from this type list? For example, if I set `MyList = TypeList<int, float, const char*>`, I wish a method

```
void my_method(int, float, const char*)
```

to be declared.

Comment: What are you going to do with a function of unknown signature (eg.: `void my_method(T0, T1, T2, ... TN)` with N <= huge)?

Comment: @DieterLücking Numerous things! (This is irrelevant to the asked question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could derive from a base class that implements the method:

```
template <typename> struct MethodProvider;

template <typename ...Args>
struct MethodProvider<TypeList<Args...>>
{
    void my_method(Args ...args);
};

template <typename T>
struct MyClassAux
{
    using MyList = TypeList<T, typename Something<T>::type, SomethingElse>;
};

template <typename T>
struct MyClass
    : private MyClassAux<T>
    , private MethodProvider<typename MyClassAux<T>::MyList>
{
    using typename MyClassAux<T>::MyList;
    using MethodProvider<typename MyClassAux<T>::MyList>::my_method;

    // ...
};
```

Comment: Wow, nice three-classes-scheme. Is this the simplest way possible?

Comment: @TigranSaluev: It's the simplest thing *I* can think of, but wait and see... note the edit, I was missing a specialization.

Comment: by the way, is it possible to access any other methods and fields of `MyClass` from `my_method` in such a setting?

Comment: @TigranSaluev: Sure, you can do whatever you want. I'd even make the inheritance private and use using declarations to make the function public i the derived class; that way, the base classes become pure implementation details. [Updated demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ckfxa9xcDKGPGSqg)

Comment: Yet I guess that to do whatever I want I have to move all the stuff (fields, methods) to `MyClassAux` (which is then reasonable to call `MyClassImplementation`) and pass this class to `MethodProvider` as one more template argument (and probably provider should also inherit it...).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `static_assert` and `std::is_same` to constraint the arguments of `my_method`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Types> struct TypeList {};

template<class T> struct MyClass {
    using MyList = TypeList<int, T>;

    template<typename ...Args>
    void my_method(Args ...args) {
        static_assert(std::is_same<MyList, TypeList<Args...>>::value, "invalid arguments");
        auto dummy = {(std::cout << args << "\n", 0)...};
        (void)(dummy); // avoid variable warning
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<float> c;
    c.my_method(1, 2.3f);
//    c.my_method(1, ""); // unmatched arguments won't compile
//    c.my_method(1);
}
```

[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a9756e8abe4027b)

Comment: This kills type conversion when calling the method, right? (Because it will just be like "oh noes, this can't be const T&, it is supposed to be exactly T!")

Comment: @TigranSaluev You are right. But you can use a custom version of `std::is_same` to release the constraint by `std::decay` all the types first.

Comment: That will fix only most trivial conversions, and will not fix conversions like `int` to `float`.

Comment: @TigranSaluev you can use `std::is_convertible` to check, but it may go too far